# how to install tensorflow to canopy

Tags: python-3.x, windows-7, 32bit-64bit, canopy

I am using canopy Version: 2.1.6.3665 (32 bit). Looking for help to install tensorflow. I tried following command using canopy command promt, however it didn't work
pip3 install --upgrage tensorflow
thanks

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: "didn't work" ? -- what was the output?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the tensorflow package is only distributed in 64 bit wheels (see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow). Why do you need to use 32-bit Python?